# Wordpress - generate random unique number using atomic operation and update database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have created a table called `wp_tickets` which contains a range of ticket numbers generated from a custom field set in my wordpress post. The columns in the table are  `'id', 'ticket_id', 'lottery_id'` and `'used'`.

I'm trying to generate a random unique number when a customer purchases the products on my website.

For example, if  a customer orders five of the same product. It needs to generate 5 random unique numbers based on the field set in the product meta field, `'maximum_entries'` and then mark those numbers as 'used' in the `wp_tickets` table.

I need to this to be an atomic operation so customers can't have the same number if they order at the same time.

So far, i've created a function to be called on the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook which loops through each product in the cart and gets the product qty. I've then used the range function to turn this into an array of numbers before calling array_rand.

I then use the `$ticketallocated` in my `$wpdb` update function.

The problem i have is if the number being generated is already marked as 'used' in the table then it doesn't loop back to the top and try again. I need to somehow setup an if/else statement so if the random number being generated is 5 and there's already a 5 in the database as 'used' then it will try a different number.

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $qty = get_field('maximum_entries');
    $array = range(1, $qty);

    foreach ($array as $ticket) {
     $wpdb->insert('wp_tickets', array(
         'ticket_number' => $ticket,
         'lottery_id' => $post_id,
     ));
    }
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'ektgn_meta_to_line_item', 20, 4 );

function ektgn_meta_to_line_item( $order_id )
{

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $product_id = $item_product->get_product_id();
        $qty = get_field('maximum_entries', $product_id, true);
        $ticketOptions = range(1, $qty);
        $ticketAllocated = array_rand($ticketOptions, 1);

        $wpdb->query(
            "
            UPDATE wp_tickets 
            SET used = 1
            WHERE ticket_number= ".$ticketAllocated." AND lottery_id = ".$product_id." AND used = 0
            "
);     

}             

}
```

Comment: While it might be possible to do this with a database I would recommend you use a proper fifio queue like `beanstalkd` and pre-populate it with unique random ticket_numbers.

Comment: Hi @Geoffrey I think i've managed to get it working within the database now. What is the downside of using a database as opposed to fifio queue?

Comment: @Geoffrey do you think using a database may cause problems then?

Comment: Provided you have a true atomic operation it should be fine, it just will not be as performant as a dedicated fifo queue. Also since you have a working solution please post your answer to this question and accept it.

Comment: Hi @Geoffrey, I've provided the solution which has worked for me. It would be great if you could have a look through and see if what i've done is a 'true atomic operation'. I suspect it's not as i'm calling multiple functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by creating two functions. One responsible for getting all the available numbers from within the `wp_tickets` table  where `used = 0` and `lottery_id = $postID` which returns a single random number from the available tickets numbers.

The second function is then responsible for updating the `wp_tickets` table with the ticket number generated from the `get_available_numbers` function.

Both these functions are then being executed on the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook when a customer orders and is being run for each item found in their cart.

So far when i've tested it, It seems to work. However, it's hard to say how this perform with multiple customers ordering at the same time.

```
function get_available_numbers($postID) {
            global $wpdb;
                $result = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "
                    SELECT ticket_number
                    FROM wp_tickets
                    WHERE lottery_id = ".$postID." AND used = 0
                    ORDER BY RAND()
                    LIMIT 1
                    "
                    );
            return $result[0]->ticket_number;
}


function add_ticket_number($postID, $order_id, $number, $user_id) {
        global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->query(
            "
            UPDATE wp_tickets
            SET used = 1, order_id = ".$order_id.", user_id = ".$user_id."
            WHERE ticket_number= ".$number." AND lottery_id = ".$postID." AND used = 0
            "
                    );
}


for ( $i = 0; $i < $item_meta['_qty'][0]; $i++ ) {
                        $number = $this->get_available_numbers($product_id);
                        $this->add_ticket_number($product_id, $order_id, $number, $order->get_user_id());
                    }
```

**UPDATE**

I've actually managed to shorten this to just one function by setting `used=1` on the `lottery_id` column and ordering the update to be random and limited by one.

```
function add_ticket_number($postID, $order_id, $user_id) {
        global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->query(
            "
            UPDATE wp_tickets
            SET used = 1, order_id = ".$order_id.", user_id = ".$user_id."
            WHERE lottery_id = ".$postID." AND used = 0
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 1
            "
                    );
}
```

Comment: The first way doesn't seems like true locking but the second way (the update) does. I do advise to handle case where all numbers has been assigned

Comment: Hi David, sorry what do you mean by 'handle case where all numbers have been assigned'?

Comment: What will happens if the `WHERE` clause will return empty?

Comment: Thanks David. The numbers are based from the stock quantities set by each product so I'm hoping that when all numbers have been assigned, the customer shouldn't be allowed to complete the purchase anyway. However, I haven't tested this thoroughly so there might be something i've not thought about. My plan is to test this on the exiting website in backend so no numbers are visible to the customer and see how it performs. Unless there is a way to programmatically test multiple orders on Wordpress?

Comment: I'm not familiar so well with Wordpress to say if there is such a way (test multiple orders)